# Switching between multiple schema with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are developing REST service in EF6, My application switches between multiple schema in the database with respect to the service call input. But i could not able to switch between multiple schema with EF.

I have implemented `OnModelCreating`, but its only called one time. For example, I have user table, first time it will call `OnModelCreating` with "schema1.user" and in the second time when I tried to call "schema2.user", it will return the "schema1.user" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF caches created models for the productivity purposes. That's why `OnModelCreating` is called once per app domain and context type.

To achieve what you want, you can make such hierarchy of `DbContext` descendants:

```
class MyDbContextBase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    // other code here;
    // DO NOT override OnModelCreating in this class
}

class MyDbContextA : MyDbContextBase 
{
     // override OnModelCreating here; 
     // e.g. map Users to schema1.user table
}

class MyDbContextB : MyDbContextBase 
{
     // override OnModelCreating here; 
     // e.g. map Users to schema2.user
}
```

Later, when you will need to process request, create appropriate context instance, depending on request parameters.

Comment: I am using generic code to create the model. Below is my code structure      internal class DBContextConnection<T> : DbContext
                        where T : class
    {
        
        public DBContextConnection()
            : base("Connection")
        {

        }
    
    

        public DbSet<T> Model { get; set; }

  

        protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
        {
            base.OnModelCreating ( modelBuilder );
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema ( _schemaName );
        }
  }

Comment: @NajiAboo: actually, I don't understand, what do you want to say with your comment. Generic code, OK. So what?